# Is Local Binary Pattern gaussian distributed?

Tags: computer-vision, classification, pattern-recognition

Local Binary Pattern is a way to determine a pixel, with a single number by comparing the center pixel with its neigbours. The result will be a binary number. Dos this number have a **gaussian** **distribution**?

[image]